# Project in Eclipse contains only a .project file

Tags: eclipse, perforce

I have several projects in Perforce that I need to maintain in Eclipse. I did a successful import the first time, but I've since removed all projects from the workspace and deleted the Perforce files from the P4 folder. I'm not very familiar with Perforce so I'm not sure why whenever I try to re-import those projects, all I get is a .project file instead of the whole package.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have to do the Eclipse equivalent of 'sync -f' rather than just 'sync'. If you physically remove files from your client machine, the Perforce server still thinks that you have them, so an ordinary 'sync' command won't resend them. The 'sync -f' command resends all the files, even those that the server thinks you already have.

Comment: Bryan is correct.  I think "Get Latest Revision" from the Team menu when you right click on your project should do a sync -f.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that there was a problem with my Perforce connection as well because whenever I did a Get Latest Revision, the Syncing would get stuck and never finish. Anyway, its working now and thank you again! :)